# Why is couchdb looking for "_users" database?

Tags: nosql, erlang, couchdb

What does this error mean in CouchDB logs? I see that it is looking for some "_users" database. But I don't have a database with that name. Is there anything I can do to stop these errors?

```
[notice] 2021-10-12T14:36:18.259160Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.328.0> -------- chttpd_auth_cache changes listener died database_does_not_exist at mem3_shards:load_shards_from_db/6(line:395) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/1(line:370) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/2(line:399) <= mem3_shards:for_docid/3(line:86) <= fabric_doc_open:go/3(line:39) <= chttpd_auth_cache:ensure_auth_ddoc_exists/2(line:195) <= chttpd_auth_cache:listen_for_changes/1(line:142)
              
[error] 2021-10-12T14:36:18.259219Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 emulator -------- Error in process <0.2113.0> on node 'couchdb@127.0.0.1' with exit value:                                                                                             {database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_users",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,395}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,370}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,399}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,86}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,39}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,ensure_auth_ddoc_exists,2,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,195}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,listen_for_changes,1,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,142}]}]}
```

Comment: https://github.com/apache/couchdb-docker/issues/54

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution in Couchdb documentation

https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/setup/single-node.html

Make sure to create the three system databases manually on startup:

curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/_users

curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/_replicator

curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/_global_changes

Note that the last of these is not necessary if you do not expect to be using the global changes feed. Feel free to delete this database if you have created it, it has grown in size, and you do not need the function (and do not wish to waste system resources on compacting it regularly.)

Answer (score 1):

Setup is not complete. See [Setup](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/setup/index.html) section of documentation.

> CouchDB 2.x can be deployed in either a single-node or a clustered
> configuration. This section covers the first-time setup steps required
> for each of these configurations.

#### [Single Node Setup](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/setup/single-node.html)

> After installation and initial startup, visit Fauxton at
> http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils#setup